# Company Search on LinkedIn API with PHP?

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

This is making me crazy. I've been trying out all sorts of things but I just can't figure this out. LinkedIn's documentation is horrible...

All I need to do is simple: I need to search for a company (using a keyword) and retrieve the company id. I have issues with setting up the OAuth request and with making the request. Any advice on how to do this, especially without installing any PHP libraries?

FYI, my code: I got the OAuth.php from [here](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/).

```
require_once 'OAuth.php';
$base_url   = 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search';
$consumer   = new OAuthConsumer('mykey', 'mysecret');
$token      = new OAuthToken('tokenkey', 'tokensecret');
$parameters = array (keyword => 'Apple');
$request    = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, "GET", $base_url, $parameters);
print_r($request);
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about PHP, but normally you need to make the OAuth request and store the cookies returned and use them for the following requests.

Comment: @thatidiotguy ok I added my code

Answer (score 1):

You're using a good OAuth library that I do recommend, but it seems to me you're missing on the Linkedin Library, or at least you haven't included the full code.

In any case, try using the simple-linkedinphp library, which uses your oauth library above. I had to use a few libraries in the past, and this is one of the best, particuarly if you're going to use Faceted search. Make sure you also check the [quick start](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/wiki/QuickStart?tm=6#Quick_Start_Guide) guide, it will help you a lot, as well as the class reference. The company search API function could be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/wiki/Reference#Company_Search_API).

You could always use the `raw()` function for any custom calls not supported by the above function. I had to use that for some calls.